# Website navigation not working in WKWebview

Tags: javascript, ios, wordpress

I have following website which are developed in `Wordpress`.

[Crypto Earn Money](https://www.cryptoearnmoney.com/)

I'm making web-view application and loading this single website inside it by using following code.

```
if let url = URL(string: "www.cryptoearnmoney.com") {
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.load(urlRequest)
}
```

Initially website load completely. But when I click on any link inside website it doesn't work. It's also not work in `Safari` and `Chrome` browser of iOS. This working fine in `Android`, `Mac OS`, `Windows` and other all except `iOS`.

I have also enabled `javascript` and `third-parties cookies`. But it not work.

Is anything wrong with web site?

Comment: If it is not working in safari and chrome browser then its the issue with the website. If you make it work in all browsers it will work in web view too.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it's Working**

Transport security you must need to use `HTTP` or `HTTPS` in Domain.

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.cryptoearnmoney.com/"){
       let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)
       webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

You have to set the **Allow Arbitrary Loads** key to **YES** under **App Transport Security Settings** dictionary in your **.plist** file.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have already done this, now days it's common thing.

Comment: @SagarChauhan I know Dear but with this, I call in my app and it's working fine. you call **"www.cryptoearnmoney.com"** and I just replace it with "https://www.cryptoearnmoney.com/"

Comment: Let me check and will know you.